# Access delete all except max value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to prune an Access table (contam) full of duplicates and concatenated values.

The table looks like this

```
FederalSiteIdentifier Contam
001 1
001 1, 2
001 1, 2, 3
001 1, 2, 3, 4
002 1
003 1
003 1, 2
003 1, 2, 3
```

I only want to keep the last - longest - entry for each ID, but cannot figure out the proper way to do this in Access SQL.

After doing some reading I tried this simple code:

```
SELECT FederalSiteIdentifier, Max(Contam) as MaxCont
FROM contam
ORDER BY FederalSiteIdentifier
```

which produces an error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suspect it'll be an aggregate with no group by error...

Comment: Surely you will be flattening this file at some stage? If so, it would be a lot easier, and safer, to delete after flattening the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the maximum length of the `Contam` values for each `FederalSiteIdentifier`.  You will need a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT FederalSiteIdentifier, Max(Len(Contam)) as MaxCont
FROM contam
GROUP BY FederalSiteIdentifier
```

If that query identifies the rows you wish to keep, save it as *qryRows2Keep*, then try this `DELETE` query:

```
DELECT FROM contam
WHERE
    Len(Contam) < DLookup(
            "MaxCont",
            "qryRows2Keep", 
            "FederalSiteIdentifier = '" & FederalSiteIdentifier & "'")
```

I assumed `FederalSiteIdentifier` is text data type.  If it is numeric, discard the single quotes from the `DLookup` expression.

Please make sure you have backed up your data before attempting this untested suggestion.  :-)

Comment: I reworked the top bit of code and it did exactly the trick, I didn't need to delete just filter it to the point where I can load it into a spreadsheet. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

MAX is an aggregate function, you can only do these if you use a GROUP BY statement. Access is also very peculiar in the way it can delete records. You can't left join and delete so you have to identify the records you don't want and then delete them.

Create a new column so we can choose the records to keep.

```
ALTER TABLE contam ADD Keep BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Now identify the records and update the table

```
UPDATE c
SET    keep = 1
FROM   contam AS c
       INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT FederalSiteIdentifier, Max(Len(Contam)) as MaxCont
                  FROM contam
                  GROUP BY FederalSiteIdentifier
                  ORDER BY FederalSiteIdentifier
                  ) AS maxc
         ON c.FederalSiteIdentifier = maxc.FederalSiteIdentifier
         AND Len(c.Contam) = maxc.MaxCont;
```

Note the GROUP BY line...that's what you missed that was giving you an error..

Finally perform the delete

```
 DELETE FROM contam
 WHERE keep = 0;
```

You can now remove the extra column

```
ALTER TABLE contam DROP COLUMN Keep;
```

Long winded but there you go.

Comment: I have changed my answer, this will work properly. Not enough coffee last night.